# django-admin.py makemessages creates no files

Tags: django, localization, django-admin, translation

I'm trying to enable translations for a django project and `django-admin.py makemessages -l de` doesn't seem to create any .po files, although there is a couple of `{% trans ... %}` in templates and a couple of `gettext(...)` in models for tests.
Accorgin to the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages, the command should search for translations in the whole project tree and create corresponding files in e.g. `conf/locale` directory if no setting is specified.
The only output I get is `processing locale ru`.

Any way to debug it or maybe well known pitfalls that I didn't find in google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me answer my own question :)

The problem was that I:

1. Didn't `import gettext as _` but did `import gettext as t`, thus makemessage didn't recognize translated strings in .py files
2. Tried to translate non-existing variables in templates instead of strings. `{% trans some_var %}` instead of `{% trans "some_string" %}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following settings available in your settings.py file:

```
DJANGO_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
SITE_ROOT = dirname(DJANGO_ROOT)
USE_I18N = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    SITE_ROOT + '/locale',
)
```

If the LOCALE_PATHS value is not set it does not know where it should create the locale directories and translation files, also you don't have to have the DJANGO_ROOT and SITE_ROOT values that's just for ease of use.

Comment: I have it like this in settings.py:
`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)`